# How do I get the URL dynamic parameter/slug inside an API Route Handler within the app folder of Next.js?

Tags: next.js

Using Next.js 13 with the `app` directory, I have tried a lot of different ways, but I can't seem to get adequation documentation on this.

I am trying to fetch this URL `/api/stripe/${sessionId}` to the server-side API path that looks like this `api/stripe/[session]/route.j`s and retrieves the `sessionId` to make a stripe call:

```
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRETE_KEY);

export async function GET(req) {
  const { sessionId } = NextRequest.nextUrl.searchParams;
  console.log(sessionId);

  const checkoutSession = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(sessionId);

  return NextResponse.json({ checkoutSession });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [Route Handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#dynamic-route-segments) gets passed an object as a parameter, which contains a `params` key that will contain the slug, like so:

```js
// app/api/stripe/[session]/route.js

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request, { params }) {
  console.log(params.session);
  // ...
  return NextResponse.json({ messsage: "Hello World" }, { status: 200 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this structure, where the **page** and **api** share the same slug. This is how you will get the same param in each of those, because the way is a bit different every time.

```
/app
 ├── /[slug] // <- "slug"
 |   ├── page.tsx
 |   ├── interfaces.d.ts
 |   └── /api
 |       └── route.tsx
 ...
```

###### `interfaces.d.ts`

```ts
export interface PageProps {
  params: { slug: string } // <- the same "slug" and any other segments
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }
}
```

###### `page.tsx`

```ts
export async function Page({ params: { slug }, searchParams }: PageProps) {
  return <>hi {slug}</>
}

export async function generateMetadata({ params: { slug }, searchParams }: PageProps, parent: ResolvingMetadata): Promise<Metadata> {
  return {
    other: {
      "my-slug": slug,
    },
  }
}
```

###### `api/route.ts`

```ts
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, { params: { slug } }: Pick<PageProps, 'params'>): Promise<Response> {
  return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({
    slug,
    searchParams: req.nextUrl.searchParams.entries()
  }))
}
```